# Confidence interval for Brier score in R

Tags: r, logistic, scoring-rules

I am using the lrm function in the rms package in R to fit a logistic regression model. The function outputs various useful stats, including Brier score.

[image]

Is it possible to output the confidence interval for these statistics, especially the Brier score?

If not then what are the other ways of doing this?

EDIT: The calculation of the confidence interval is somehow related to the [Spiegelhalter’s z-statistic](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/elsevier/use-of-brier-score-to-assess-binary-predictions-07s7yZIaxK). I am not sure how. The [brier](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rbrier.pdf#rbrier) function in STATA does output this statistic.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess confidence interval of the Brier score maybe calculated by calculating the confidence interval of the predicted probabilities.